# Select a lot og button with UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, uipangesturerecognizer

This is my problem, i want do it in multiple buttons and i only do it with one button...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3;
[longpressGesture setDelegate:self];

[self.pieza11 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
[self.pieza12 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
[self.pieza13 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
[self.pieza14 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];

    [longpressGesture release];
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one gesture works for one object only.
so in your case it might be working with the last one pieza14.

if you want this for all then you have to add separate  UILongPressGestureRecognizer to all buttons.

Comment: Some example please? im doing it:

Comment: -(IBAction)tocarLargo :(id)sender
{

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 3;
[longpressGesture setDelegate:self];

[self.pieza11 addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
}

It is correct?

Comment: dear on a button event you are adding a longPress gesture to another button. 
what really you want to do please explain it in details step by step.